# executing eclipse.buildscript task on a feature misses the fragment

Tags: eclipse, ant, osgi, eclipse-pde

I have a feature called foo, plugin called foo, and a single fragment foo.win32.x86.

I should be able to execute a call to eclipse.buildscript within an ant file on a feature and have it create a build.xml for the feature, plugin, and fragment; however, all I get is the build.xml for the feature and plugin.

The foo feature.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
  id="foo"
  label="%featureName"
  version="0.0.0.200906251500"
  provider-name="%providerName"
  plugin="foo">
<install-handler/>

<description>
  %description
</description>

<copyright>
  %copyRight
</copyright>

<license url="license.html">
  %license
</license>

<plugin
     id="foo"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="0.0.0"/>

<plugin
     id="foo.win32.x86"
     os="win32"
     arch="x86"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="0.0.0"
     fragment="true"/>

</feature>
```

The foo plugin MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Plugin.name
Bundle-SymbolicName: foo; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.200906251500
Bundle-Vendor: %Plugin.providername
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Eclipse-LazyStart: true
```

The foo plugin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?eclipse version="3.0"?>
<plugin>
   <!-- extension point stuff, blah -->
</plugin>
```

The foo.win32.x86 MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Plugin.name
Bundle-SymbolicName: foo.win32.x86
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.200906251500
Bundle-Vendor: %Plugin.providername
Fragment-Host: foo;bundle-version="0.0.0.200906251500"
Bundle-Localization: plugin
```

Can anyone explain why I'm not getting the build.xml for the fragment?

If I force a call to eclipse.buildscript for the fragment it works fine, but doesn't this defeat the purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the `configInfo` attribute.  The value is an '&' separated list of "`os,ws,arch`" triplets.  Scripts are only generated for platform specific fragments if they resolve for one of the configurations being built.  If configInfo is not specified, the default will be "`*,*,*`" which means "platform independent" (which your foo.win32.x86 doesn't match).

eg:

```
 <eclipse.buildscript 
        elements="feature@foo"
        buildDirectory="${buildDirectory}"
        baseLocation="${baseLocation}"
        configInfo="win32,win32,x86" />
```

The help page is [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_feature_generating_antcommandline.htm), which may be helpful.